# Is there a command to round decimal numbers in txt files?

Tags: command-line, bash

I saw this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179898/how-to-round-decimals-using-bc-in-bash), but I was wondering if there is a simpler command to round decimal numbers.

I have a file with milions of numbers:

```
0.1
1.2
3.8
```

I want to round them to integer

```
0
1
4
```

Is there a simple command to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following `perl` oneliner:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(\d*\.\d*)/int($1+0.5)/ge' file
```

The `-i` option will automatically change your decimal numbers in-place.

The regex `\d*\.\d*` will ensure that only such numbers will be changed in your original file (i.e other strings will be left untouched)

Comment: This answer is more elegant, can handle lines with multiple numbers.

Answer (score 3):

With the `awk` commands in the link you post, you'd get something like this:

```
awk '{printf("%d\n",$0+0.5)}' file
```

Or simpler, use:

```
awk '{printf("%.f\n",$0)}' file
```

I can come up with nothing easier than that ;)

Comment: I can: `awk '{printf("%d\n",$1 + 0.5)}' filename` ;-)

Comment: Good point, I see @Kasiya has already added it for me ;)